# Please suggest direction for my small scala project

Tags: scala, distributed-caching

As a academic project of 6 months in college me and my 3 friends are going to implement "Distributed Caching" in scala language.
Being new to both of these concepts and this being our first project I would be really happy if you guys could provide some direction.
I am currently learning scala.
Please let me know which particular features of language to be learned for this particular project.
Any online resources for learning distributed caching.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) and especially at its uses in implementing [Distributed Caching](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/docs/Terracotta+Distributed+Cache). You could have a look at the source code of the [open source edition of Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/web/display/orgsite/DownloadCatalog). Also, you could even consider Terracotta as your framework for building the distributed cache. I don't have any personal experience in using Terracotta with Scala, but [it has been done](http://jonasboner.com/2008/01/25/clustering-scala-actors-with-terracotta.html).

Features of the language... Try starting with the Programming in Scala book. It's a very good resource. If you want to do any concurrency you will have to be proficient in using `Actor`s. I would recommend having a look over all the features of Scala. Each one has its uses and you will need to know at least a bit of them to recognise situations in which to use their power. :)

-- Flaviu Cipcigan

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [project Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx) page.

In MSDN also there is an [article about distributed caching in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942840.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I  think the [Akka](http://wiki.github.com/jboner/akka) project might is already doing what you're looking for (and a whole lot more). Perhaps you can take inspiration from that.